# Hierarchy in Interfaces (.NET Framework 4.8)

Tags: c#

I have this two interfaces:

```
internal interface ClassType
    {
        string name { get; set; }
    }

internal interface ClassTexture
    {
        string texture { get; set; }
    }
```

I'm currently using them in seperate mainly for `Where T : interface`

But every class with texture has a name. Is there a way to merge them?

Comment: `interface ClassTexture : ClassType`?

Comment: List them _both_ in the where?

Comment: A class can implement multiple interfaces

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sure, interfaces may inherit from each other, like classes.

```cs
internal interface ClassTexture : ClassType
{
   string Texture { get; set; }
}
```

Note that by convention, property names should start with a capital letter.

Unlike with classes, there's no limit as to how many interfaces an interface (or a class!) may inherit from.

Answer (score 2):

Alternatively an implementation may list multiple interfaces.

```
class MyClass : ClassTexture, ClassType
{
    string Name {get;set;}
    string Texture {get;set;}
}
```